# Remove exact alphanumeric string from text in R/Python

Tags: python, r, regex, text-mining

"The string? is made up a load of strings but the problem is the removal of question mark in the word string? without removing the other question marks. can anybody have a look?"

In the above text I have to alter "string?" to "string". But I dont want the statement to lose the rest of the ? in the text.

Resultant text should be:
"The string is made up a load of strings but the problem is the removal of question mark in the word string without removing the other question marks. can anybody have a look?"

I have tried gsub, string_replace and a number of other methods, they end up removing or replacing the word and still keeping the "?"

Comment: can you mention your try also ? i mean in code

Comment: What of the second question mark

Comment: "Is this an april-fools joke?" ... Its Feb! "You go" python tutorials... burden Tarun with knowledgeable background info. Second of all.... either solution in python or R... be specific.

Comment: You tell him @ZF007! Asking solutions in either R/python is not the problem, SO questions deserve more effort than this! Tarun - as Vikas has stated, please post the code you have tried. Also, please lookup [How to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: *"I have tried......"*, where is this attempt in your question?

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan... killing the MCVE suspense... [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is for Tarun.

Comment: All the guys who have given a minus one to the question,please be kind enough to solve the problem as well. I'll repeat the question: We need to replace the word "string?" with "string" and also the question mark at the end must not get removed. TY!

Answer (score 1):

```
string.replace('string?', 'string')
```

Gives:

```
'The string is made up a load of strings but the problem is the removal of 
question mark in the word string without removing the other question marks. 
can anybody have a look?'
```